# Different Axis 1.4 Web Service Client log different logs file using log4j.xml

Tags: java, xml, web-services, log4j, axis

I am working on a financial sector project. The project has a number of web service client for different partner. Till now, the projects logs and the web service request response logs are been logged in different files, say a.log and b.log. Now, the partners wants the web service request and response logs are to be logged in different file partner wise i.e. I mean the b.log file is not required. Instead have partner1.log, partner2.log, partner3.log and so on...  . And I am using log 4j.xml for all these purpose and this not a web application. The problem is I dont know to do this ?
Making the request and response logs from the web service client in different log file seems impossible for me using log4j.xml as I have two thing  1) different partner and 2) axis request and response logs at the same time.
I am using axis 1.4 for the client and have done good homework on this
Can any one suggest me out any solutions.
Thanks in advance.

The log4j.xml is the very same we use in general.

I HAVE ALSO ADDED IT NOW.

```
**<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="FILE_APPENDER"
        class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="${basedir}/logs/Server.log" />
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern"
                value="%d %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="FILE_APPENDER_PARTNER_1"
        class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="${basedir}/logs/Server_PARTNER_1.log" />
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern"
                value="%d %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="FILE_APPENDER_PARTNER_2"
        class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="${basedir}/logs/Server_PARTNER_2.log" />
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern"
                value="%d %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="FILE_APPENDER_PARTNER_3"
        class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="${basedir}/logs/Server_PARTNER_3.log" />
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern"
                value="%d %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="FILE_APPENDER_AXIS"
        class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="${basedir}/logs/Server_AXIS.log" />
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern"
                value="%d %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <category name="org.apache.jcs">
        <level value="WARN" />
    </category>

    <category name="org.hibernate.SQL">
        <level value="WARN" />
    </category>

    <category name="org.hibernate">
        <level value="WARN" />
    </category>
    <category name="org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerAdapter">
        <level value="ERROR" />
    </category>
    <category name="com.util.PropertiesUtil">
        <level value="ERROR" />
    </category>
    <!--NEWLY ADDED-->
    <logger name="com.ws.stub.PARTNER_1">
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_APPENDER_PARTNER_1" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="com.ws.stub.PARTNER_2">
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_APPENDER_PARTNER_2" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="com.ws.stub.PARTNER_3">
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_APPENDER_PARTNER_3" />
    </logger>
    <!--AXIS-->
    <logger name="org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender">
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_APPENDER_AXIS" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.apache.axis.client.Call">
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_APPENDER_AXIS" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient">
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_APPENDER_AXIS" />
    </logger>
    <!--my one-->
    <logger name="org.apache.commons.httpclient">
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_APPENDER_AXIS" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.apache.axis.Handler">
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_APPENDER_AXIS" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.apache.axis.AxisFault">
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_APPENDER_AXIS" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.apache.axis.AxisEngine">
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_APPENDER_AXIS" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.apache.axis.handlers">
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_APPENDER_AXIS" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.apache.axis.client">
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_APPENDER_AXIS" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.apache.axis.client.Transport">
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_APPENDER_AXIS" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.apache.axis.MessageContext">
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_APPENDER_AXIS" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.apache.axis.handlers.BasicHandler">
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_APPENDER_AXIS" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.apache.axis.handlers.http.HTTPAuthHandler">
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_APPENDER_AXIS" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.apache.axis.handlers.http.HTTPActionHandler">
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_APPENDER_AXIS" />
    </logger>
    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />      
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_APPENDER" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>**
```

can any one expert over here help me out with this issue?

Comment: Take an example. I have 5 axis-1.4 client at my end. All the client send request to different servers at different locations and receive response and execute their respective services. Now I need to log them in different file for different client, the request and response xml part from axis server.

Comment: If the clients are in different package then I will have the logs for them only, not for the axis request response xml part as they will get logged for axis part only

Answer (score 0):

Solved it successfully with a bit coding efforts with axis and the application.